# Linq Account Hierarchy Drill Down

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

I have two tables, one an invoice table and the other a hierarchy table for the accounts on the invoice

Invoice Table:

```
| InvoiceNo| AccNo| InvoiceAmount |
--------------------------------------
| A1234| 345| 100.00   |
| A1235| 346| 95.00    |
| A1236| 347| 15.50    |
| A1237| 348| 20.10    |
```

Hierarchy Table

```
| AccNo| HierAccNo| Level|
--------------------------------------
| 123|    | 1    |
| 789| 123| 2    |
| 890| 123| 2    |
| 345| 789| 3    |
| 346| 789| 3    |
| 347| 890| 3    |
| 348| 890| 3    |
```

What I'm trying to do is to roll up the amounts from the invoice table to the highest level AccNo which is Level1 and then on a seperate instance from the highest account number roll back down to the next levels.

So far I am able to roll up to the highest band number by the following :

```
                var BandL2 = from invoice in db.Invoices//Roll up to level 2
                         join ban in db.HierarchyTable
                         on invoice.AccNo equals ban.Ban
                         where invoice.GlobalInvoiceID == globalInvoice.Id
                         group invoice by ban.HierAccNo into bandHierarchy
                         select new
                         {
                             Level2Band = bandHierarchy.Key,
                             Amount = bandHierarchy.Sum(m=> m.InvoiceAmount)
                         };

            var bandHierarchyTable = db.HierarchyTable.AsQueryable();

            var BandL1 = from band2 in BandL2 // Roll Up to level 1
                         join band1 in bandHierarchyTable
                         on band2.Level2Band equals band1.Ban
                         group band2 by band1.HierAccNo into bandL1
                         select new
                         {
                             Level1Band = bandL1.Key,
                             Amount = bandL1.Sum(m => m.Amount)
                         };
```

But now I'm having an issue reversing the process and drilling down from Level 1 as the only details from the form is the AccNo of Level 1(eg. 123).
I'm trying to do this on the fly using pop up modals as I'm drilling.

How do I drill down again so that I can get level by level amounts?
Example:

Ouput Table from Above Code

```
| AccNo| Amount|
--------------------------------------
| 123| 230.60 |
```

Then

```
| AccNo| Amount|
-------------------------------------- 
| 789| 195  | 
| 890| 35.60|
```

And then clicking on one of the AccNo.

```
| AccNo| Amount|
-------------------------------------- 
| 345| 100| 
| 346| 95 |
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like only leaf accounts can have invoices attached to it, so get the account number, check if it is leaf account, if it is leaf it should be something like that;

```
var hierAccNo = 123;
var details =  from invoice in db.Invoices
                         join ban in db.HierarchyTable
                         on invoice.AccNo equals ban.Ban
                         where invoice.GlobalInvoiceID == globalInvoice.Id
and ban.HierAccNo = HierAccNo;
```

if it is not leaf you want your original query on level 1 I guess to get the subtotals.

```
var BandL2 = from invoice in db.Invoices//Roll up to level 2
                         join ban in db.HierarchyTable
                         on invoice.AccNo equals ban.Ban
                         where invoice.GlobalInvoiceID == globalInvoice.Id and ban.HierAccNo = hierAccNo // dont skip this

                         group invoice by ban.HierAccNo into bandHierarchy
                         select new
                         {
                             Level2Band = bandHierarchy.Key,
                             Amount = bandHierarchy.Sum(m=> m.InvoiceAmount)
                         };
```